# Why am I Getting Null DataTable?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I created a very simple test to boil this issue down to common elements.  I have an MS Access DB with 1 and only 1 table in it.  2 columns (ID, Name) and added 4 rows of data to the table.   Here is the steps to reproduce the problem:

- I added a `DataSet` containing a `DataTable` to datasources of my project. (Add new datasource from database)
- I added a test `Form1` with 1 and only 1 control, a `DataGridView`
- Using designer I bound that grid to the table in the datasources of project. (Using `DataSource` property of `DataGridView` at design-time).

My `Form_Load` looks like this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'testDBDataSet.TestTable' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    this.testTableTableAdapter.Fill(this.testDBDataSet.TestTable);

    BindingSource bs = (BindingSource)dgvTestData.DataSource;
    DataTable dt = (dgvTestData.DataSource) as DataTable;            
}
```

When I step past the last line of code, dt is null.  What am I missing?

I know it is something simple and probably obvious, but I don't see it.  If I just run the code back to the form, the `DataGridView` has data in it.

What am I doing wrong? How can I get the underlying `DataTable` from `BindingSource` which is set as `DataSource` of my `DataGridView` using above steps?

Comment: You really need to provide a [mcve]. Right now the only thing that can be said is that `dgvTestData.DataSource` is not a non-`null` `DataTable`. Nothing in your question shows how you have actually assigned the `DataSource` so we really can't say anything other that you need to make sure you assign it properly.

Comment: @Enigmativity I edited the post to make it more clear for future readers to know what the problem is and what settings has been used. The OP is binding a `DataGridView` to a `DataTable` of a `DataSet` using designer by setting `DataSource` property of `DataGrid`. The codes are automatically generated and the OP has nothing else to share with us. The case is familiar for a developer who is experienced in using data-binding and designer tools,but anyway I tried to make it more clear for for other readers too. Hope you find it useful :)

Comment: @RezaAghaei - That's not useful at all. The OP should at least post the designer code that sets the `DataSource`. The really should provide a [MCVE]. If they did so then the problem would likely to self resolve. Right now this is a bit of lazy question. The OP should do all the hard work in making the question easy to answer.

Comment: @Enigmativity For experienced users it's enough IMO :)

Comment: @RezaAghaei Yes, that's probably true, but SO exists as a repository for inexperienced users to find a library of good quality questions and answers. Experienced users, almost by definition, already know the answer.

Comment: @Enigmativity You are right, experienced users may know the answer, so I made it more understandable for inexperienced users. I believe the post doesn't deserve such amount of down votes. In fact it's a good question. What's the problem with current contents of the question? Instead of a lot of useless designer generated codes, currently it describes complete steps for reproducing the problem. What kind of MCVE is supposed to be posted? Not all MCVEs need code.

Comment: @RezaAghaei - From the [mcve] page - "When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. That code should be…"

Comment: @Enigmativity I also believe users should spend enough time to post a good question and post MCVE if possible. In this question all of the settings has been done using the designer (the op had said that in the post, but I made it more clear), so I believe sharing designer steps is enough and for Windows Forms developers it's an MCVE now. Isn't it? surely posting such amount of useless designer generated code which makes the question unreadable is really useless.

Comment: *When asking a question about a problem caused by your code ...* Here the most important part of reproducing the problem is steps which is done using designer.

Comment: @RezaAghaei - One of the key aspects of an MCVE is to post the minimal amount of code required. That would be three or four lines in this case I would think. Nothing much more than `this.fooBindingSource = new System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource(this.components); this.dataGridView1.DataSource = this.fooBindingSource;` would suffice.

Comment: @Enigmativity Why do you think steps of designer is not enough? How do an inexperienced user know they should post that part of designer generated code while they can post designer steps which is really more useful? Maybe they forget to include `this.fooBindingSource.DataSource = this.fooDataSet; this.fooBindingSource.DataMember = "barTable";` like you did or even they don't know its importance. They don't know designer generated code. In such cases they don't reproduce the problem using designer codes, they reproduce the problem using designer.

Comment: The main point of the question is they don't know anything about behind the scene. Also future readers perform steps using designer. If the OP say I set `DataSource` of grid using designer to a `DataTable` in `DataSet`, It will be more useful for future readers. Also more useful for a person who knows the progress of data-binding and knows designer, to answer the question.

Comment: @RezaAghaei - No, I disagree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What am I doing wrong?**

When `dgvTestData.DataSource` is `BindingSource` you can not expect `dgvTestData.DataSource as DataTable` return anything else than null.

The [`as`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) operator is like a cast operation. However, if the conversion isn't possible, as returns null instead of raising an exception.

**How can I get the underlying DataTable from BindingSource?**

It seems you bound the grid to a binding source which its `DataSource` is set to a `DataSet` and its `DataMember` is name of a `DataTable`. It's the default behavior when you set data source of grid to a table using designer or drag a `Table` from Data Sources Window and drop on your form. So if you are following default scenarios, you can use such code to get the `DataTable`:

```
BindingSource bs = (BindingSource)dgvTestData.DataSource;
var dt = (bs.DataSource as DataSet).Tables[bs.DataMember];
```

If you are using any other scenario different than the default scenario, you can simply use `DataSource` and `DataMember` properties of your binding sources to extract the `DataTable` which is using for data-binding.

**Is there a better way?**

It depends, why not simply use:

```
var dt = this.testDBDataSet.TestTable;
```

Comment: Thank you SOOOO much Reza!  That is the exact information I needed.  At the end of the day, I am making edits to the data in the table via a gridview.  I didnt realize that the changes I make in the grid were actually being changed to the actual underlying dataset.  I thought that a partition existed between what happened in the gridview and the actual underlying (in mem) data.  Now that i understand that, my job got tons easier!  Thanks much!!!